# Manual refresh button for the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface

I know the perfect solution would be auto-update, but until that we could put a simple refresh button to the [review pages](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts).

I always press <kbd>F5</kbd> to find out if there are new posts to review, but this refreshes the whole page. I also realized that for first the page loads itself, then while it says `loading item`, it starts to load the posts in an AJAXy way. What I suggest is to make a refresh button that we can click on, and this could trigger the same `loading item` process. This would also save bandwidth and server process because it doesn't need to redownload the whole page, just the posts. It could look like this:

[image: Refresh button for post review]

Comment: I don't think it's that urgent that users can eat their way even faster through this rapidly-emptied queue.

Comment: Not to disagree at all with the request, but wouldn't it be just as easy to implement the auto-refresh at that point as it would be to add the button to do a manual refresh?

Comment: Use [review stalker](http://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script)

Comment: @jprofitt Maybe they don't want to create an auto-refresh...