# Append a note to "There are no items for you to review." to suggest refreshing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

When coming from the review queues page to a specific queue, which may be empty, the message *"There are no items for you to review."* is presented.

I do not believe many SO users realize they can simply refresh a specific review page and be potentially presented with a new item to review.  I suspect many users go back to the review queues page, which contains cached counts that are potentially inaccurate, and refresh it instead.

**I suggest changing the empty review queue message to something which indicates that refreshing the page may provide the user with a new item to review**; though I am unsure what the new text should be as anything I can think of seems too unwieldy.

Ideas:

- *There are no items for you to review; try refreshing the page.*

Suggestions welcomed as comments or answers, though more preferably I'd like feedback regarding the act of actually appending a note (any note) to suggest refreshing.

Of note to those who are concerned about robo-reviewers, adding this note would actually aid those of us who are manual reviewers by making it easier for us to find items to review. Robo-reviewers already know about refreshing.

Comment: How about "There are currently no items for you to review. You can try refreshing the page." :)

Answer (score 2):

Even better than a note that refreshing is possible, might be something like

> There are no items for you to review. You can come back later, or [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) to check again.

It reminds tech-savvy users that they can just reload the page to get anything new, and at the same time it gives less tech-savvy users a nice simple button to push.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181249/manual-refresh-button-for-the-review-queue

Answer (score 1):

How about

> There were no items for you to review; a refresh might help.

The other that we need to consider is that not everything is SO/F/U. The people over at ELU aren't exactly the most tech-savvy. Therefore, we need to be carefully how we word things. Using words like 'cache' and millisecond time stamps probably aren't recommended.

Comment: Thanks, but `At your last refresh, there were no items for you to review.` seems too backwards in presentation.  Of course, I'm not the final authority here. :-)

Comment: @Josh How's that?

Comment: `There were no items for you to review; a refresh might help.`; so they should go to the fridge and get a soda? :-)

Comment: @Josh Only the ELU people might think that :)